# How to get custom categories template?

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, wordpress-theming, categories

I have a categories page in Wordpress and it has its own template `categories.php`, which is actually a static page with boxes that link to specific categories. This is a shortened code:

```
<?php
/*
    Template Name: Categories
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<nav><?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'Main Nav Menu')); ?></nav>

<div id="main-content-categories">

    <h5 class="inner_text_shadow">Categories & Tags</h5>

    <div id="clear-box">

    <a href="/category/locations"><div id="cc" class="c1"><h6>The Fall Locations</h6></div></a>
    <a href="/category/info"><div id="cc" class="c2"><h6>Info</h6></div></a>
    <a href="/category/budget"><div id="cc" class="c3"><h6>Budget</h6></div></a>


</div> <!-- END main-content -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

CSS doesn't matter.

My question is - which PHP file/template is used for those posts that are in certain category like `www.mywebsite.com/category/budget`? When I click any of the boxes I do get the posts that are in that category but there's no formatting, just the header, sidebar and footer. What is the actual code for "posts from category" and what PHP file do I input it to?

[Same question goes for tags. (`www.mywebsite.com/tag/food`)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The category.php can handle all categories. See my example below:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php 

//Get Category
$category = get_category(get_query_var('cat'));

?>

    <!-- Start Loop -->
    <?php query_posts('category_name=' . $category->cat_name . '&paged='. get_query_var('paged')); ?>           

    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <!-- Loop Code Here -->         

    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
            <p>An Error Occurred</p>
    <?php endif; ?> 


    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    <!-- End Loop -->


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

You can also have separate files for each category in the format category-slug.php. In your case you would have category-locations.php, category-info.php & category-budget.php

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks...
The problem was that the blank theme that I used for building my theme didn't have `category.php`, only `categories.php` and since I'm new in building WP themes, hmmm...
Do you maybe know where from does the "category view" of the posts reference that category.php file?